# Ubuntu mate raspberry pi SD card issue

Tags: sd-card, ubuntu-mate, raspberrypi

I am attempting to install ubuntu mate 16:04 on an SD card for use on a Raspberry pi 3.

Working on a mac, I have use Etcher to write the img (ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img), to my sd card.

The problem is when the pi is powered on with the sd card in it, the installation process does not initiate. Instead, I get the following:

[image]

I have tried different SD cards without success.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If you are using an RPi you don't install the ISO, you install the prebuilt images.  Did you verify the image was valid?  (It might not have been, check the hash sums and such)

Comment: did you follow this guide: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0 ? I have had similar problem from doing an incorrect initial format on the USB drive. It's super important the disk is formatted EXACTLY as described in the tutorial BEFORE writing with etcher.... also, did you check your ISO sum to ensure download was not corrupt?

Comment: My apologies. I said ISO when I meant to say IMG